# How can I write the symbol t̬ in TeX?

Tags: tipa, phonetic

In terms of the phonetic symbol, how can I write the symbol t̬ , a "t" with an *upside* down "^" under it?

Comment: Have a look at the tipa package, as described e.g. in https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb17-2/tb51rei.pdf

Comment: See this answer here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241820/90297

Comment: Does this answer your question? [an \underhat and \underwidehat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241814/an-underhat-and-underwidehat)

Comment: @EladDen — the `underaccent` package is designed for math-mode usage. Throwing in a few `\mathrm` corrections is order to create a semblance of text mode will mess up the positioning of the hat and caron accent symbols.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I add a minimal working example for your request.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{ifxetex}<------from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464082/xelatex-font-shape-t3-lmr-m-n-undefinedfont-using-t3-cmr-m-n-insteadfont
\ifxetex
  \usepackage{substitutefont}
  \substitutefont{T3}{\rmdefault}{cmr}
\fi

\begin{document}
\textsubwedge{t}, \textsubcircum{t}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I add minimal working example using OpTeX:

```
\fontfam[libertine]
symbol t̬  
\bye
```

The main point is: use Unicode font which supports these combining diacritical marks. If this is true then you can type natural t̬ if you know how to do it in your editor and keyboard. Or you can define a macro `\def\t{t̬}` and use `\t` (the plain TeX old `\t` is re-defined in such case but we don't use it).